# Measuring group homogeneity

Tags: variance

I am trying to answer a hypothesis wherein companies with more heterogenous boards are more compliant and less likely to attempt fraud than companies with homogenous boards.

So in effect I have a dataset containing hundreds of thousands of companies and details about the people behind each and everyone of them (such as age, sex, income level etc)

Now I need to find a way to quantify similarity. The one approach I have tried is to calculate cosine distance from each board member to each board member within a single company and then take an average of these distances. I am, however, not particularly satisfied with this approach.

I have tried to scour the internet for different measures to calculate for this kind of problem but haven't come up with any. Clustering indexes don't seem to apply here.

Any idea on what to try? I would need the measurement to be standardized to certain range and preferably as robust as possible against differing board sizes.

Comment: Very interesting problem :-). Do you know the Mahalanobis distance? That one takes care for different variation within each of the variables.
(will be away for the next 8 hours or so, but am anxious to see what has happened here by then)

Comment: The topic seems to be quite popular in research. I found for example this paper [The Economics of Director Heterogeneity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41237895). They use a variety of different statistical methods.

Comment: Thanks for great article! That made decide to check homogeneity not only as a composite index but also along individual variables.

Anyway, I decided to go for Gower's distance as my metric as it facilitates categorical variables. 

Results were unimpressive, but hey, atleast it's done now :D

Comment: As far as I could see when I glanced over that paper, they have discretized all their continuous variables exactly because categorial variables are apparently easier to handle